# Make custom title view click able swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I customise the title view add a image and labels in it know I want to make it clickable but its not working. I added tap gesture in title view but its not  working.

here is my code.

```
func navTitleWithImageAndText(titleText: String,subTitleText:String, imageName: String) -> UIView {
        // Creates a new UIView
        let titleView = UIView()
         let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -15, width: 0, height: 0))
        // Creates a new text label
       // let label = UILabel()
        label.text = titleText
        
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
        //label.center = titleView.center
        label.textColor = .white
        //label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        label.sizeToFit()
        
        let subtitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 0, height: 0))
        subtitleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        subtitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        subtitleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        subtitleLabel.text = subTitleText
        subtitleLabel.sizeToFit()

        // Creates the image view
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        // Maintains the image's aspect ratio:
        let imageAspect = image.image!.size.width / image.image!.size.height

        // Sets the image frame so that it's immediately before the text:
        let imageX = label.frame.origin.x - label.frame.size.height * imageAspect - 20
        let imageY = label.frame.origin.y
        let imageWidth = label.frame.size.height * imageAspect + 15
        let imageHeight = label.frame.size.height + 15
        image.frame = CGRect(x: imageX, y: imageY, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
        image.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        // Adds both the label and image view to the titleView
        titleView.addSubview(label)
        titleView.addSubview(image)
        titleView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)
        // Sets the titleView frame to fit within the UINavigation Title
        titleView.sizeToFit()
        return titleView
    }
```

add tap gesture in it. but why its not working.

```
titleView.addGestureRecognizer(titleGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `UIButton`? Does your code work when not using as a title view, but a simple view?

Comment: @DávidPásztor is added UIbutton but still its not working.

Comment: Is it working if you use the same view simply on a `UIViewController`, not as a title view on the navbar? By testing that you can check whether the problem is with your view or with the way you add it as the title view (which you didn't include in the question btw).

Comment: I think your view is behind the title, subtitle, & image view that's why it doesn't tap.  You have to add a gesture on your title label.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I am using same tap gesture its working fine. when i  add self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(titleGestureRecognizer) it also work but it also call when I click on back button.

Comment: @AshutoshkumarMishra did the same but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have implemented a tap gesture on a label in the following way:-**

*Initialize Variable*

```
var tap_gest = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

**Add gesture on Label. Add the following code in "viewDidLoad()"**

*if normal label then use below*

```
self.register_as_company_lbl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // register_as_company_lbl is my label where tap gesture added
self.tap_gest.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registerAsComapany))
self.register_as_company_lbl.addGestureRecognizer(tap_gest)
```

*if on navigation bar title then use below*

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(tap_gest)
```

**Define Selector method in your ViewController Class as following**

```
 @objc func registerAsComapany(){//Add your task what you perform, In my case I have to push to another screen
     let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CompanyDetailsViewController") as! CompanyDetailsViewController
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc , animated: true)
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans I did it like this.
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(titleGestureRecognizer)

Comment: Great, I think it's best practice if you have a hint, USE THEM.

Comment: yes its working fine. and don't forget to upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true